# Fazer uma contagem até 100 com PHP

Tags: php, array, while

Preciso completar o array `$resultado` utilizando o parâmetro `$numero` até 100.

Por exemplo, se `$numero` fosse 45, `$resultado` deveria ter os números de 45 até 100, o número 100 também deve ser incluído.

```php
<?php

function conta100 ($base) {
    $resultado = [];
    $numero = 45;

    while($numero<=100){
        echo $numero;
        $numero++;
    }

    return $resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu `while` está correto, basta então adicionar o a variável `$numero` no array, para isso você pode por exemplo utilizar a função `array_push`:

```
array_push($resultado, $numero);
```

Ou utilizar a sintaxe com colchetes:

```
$resultado[] = $numero;
```

---

Também alteramos o parâmetro recebido para `$numero` e removemos a linha que força o início sempre em 45:

```
function conta100($numero) {
```

---

Seu código então ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

function conta100($numero ) {
    $resultado = [];

    while($numero<=100){
        //Utilizando array_push
        array_push($resultado, $numero);
        $numero++;
    }

    return $resultado;
}

var_dump(conta100(45));

?>
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PoorMadeupCertifications

---

Como você sabe onde começa e termina o seu loop, uma alternativa é utilizar o laço `for`:

```
<?php

function conta100($numero) {
    $resultado = [];

    for($i = $numero; $i <= 100; $i++) {
        //Utilizando colchetes
        $resultado[] = $i;
    }

    return $resultado;
}

var_dump(conta100(75));

?>
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PastelAdeptDriver

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.while.php
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Deu super certo!

Answer (score 1):

acho muito mais símples usar um `for` observe o exemplo:

```
<?php

$numero = 45;
$resultado = [];

for($i = ($numero+1);$i <= 100;$i++){
$resultado[] += $i;
}

print_r($resultado);
```

sem contar que não precisa gastar recurso chamando uma função.

usando o while:

```
//public function teste($numeroMaximo, $numeroInicial){
$numeroMaximo = 100;
$numeroInicial = 45;
$numeroInicial++;
$resultado = [];
while($numeroInicial<=$numeroMaximo){
 $resultado[] += $numeroInicial++;
}
return $resultado
}
```

Comment: Deu certo também, mas exercício pede que seja com while. Obrigada pela dica

Comment: note que eu adicionei a mesma função porém usando o while.

Comment: @MayaraMendes você tem que colocar na pergunta essa condição que o exercício só pode ser feito com `while`.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius desculpa pelo equivoco, mas obrigada pela dica ;) Deu certo !

Answer (score 1):

> **Aviso: Não resolve especificamente o exercício pois a autora da pergunta esclareceu
>   posteriormente nos comentários que o mesmo deve ser feito usando laço
>   `while`.**

Mas a maneira mais simples de criar uma array contendo uma faixa numérica continua ou salteada é utilizando a função [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php) que retorna um array numérico iniciando com o valor start até o valor end, inclusive.

```
print_r( range(45, 100) );
```

Resultando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 46
    [2] => 47
    [3] => 48
    [4] => 49
    [5] => 50
    [6] => 51
    [7] => 52
    [8] => 53
    [9] => 54
    [10] => 55
    [11] => 56
    [12] => 57
    [13] => 58
    [14] => 59
    [15] => 60
    [16] => 61
    [17] => 62
    [18] => 63
    [19] => 64
    [20] => 65
    [21] => 66
    [22] => 67
    [23] => 68
    [24] => 69
    [25] => 70
    [26] => 71
    [27] => 72
    [28] => 73
    [29] => 74
    [30] => 75
    [31] => 76
    [32] => 77
    [33] => 78
    [34] => 79
    [35] => 80
    [36] => 81
    [37] => 82
    [38] => 83
    [39] => 84
    [40] => 85
    [41] => 86
    [42] => 87
    [43] => 88
    [44] => 89
    [45] => 90
    [46] => 91
    [47] => 92
    [48] => 93
    [49] => 94
    [50] => 95
    [51] => 96
    [52] => 97
    [53] => 98
    [54] => 99
    [55] => 100
)
```

Teste o exemplo no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/PettyMessyArchitects